# POST Request is taking infinitely long

Tags: mongodb, express, rest, postman, mern

I am following an online tutorial on MERN stack (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CvCiNeLnZ00&t=1800s) that allows Users to create, view, update, and delete "notes" that have parameters like the user associated with them, the title, and text on them. I have followed the steps almost exactly and I got the CRUD operations working for the User Model. However, I am having trouble creating new notes using Postman as the POST requests for notes never finish executing. My code is as follows.

**server.js**

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const { logger, logEvents } = require('./middleware/logger')
const errorHandler = require('./middleware/errorHandler')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const corsOptions = require('./config/corsOptions')
const connectDB = require('./config/dbConn')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3500

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)

connectDB()

app.use(logger)

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.use(express.json())

app.use(cookieParser())

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.use('/', require('./routes/root'))
app.use('/users', require('./routes/userRoutes'))
app.use('/notes', require('./routes/noteRoutes'))

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404)
    if (req.accepts('html')) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', '404.html'))
    } else if (req.accepts('json')) {
        res.json({ message: '404 Not Found' })
    } else {
        res.type('txt').send('404 Not Found')
    }
})

app.use(errorHandler)

mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB')
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))
})

mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err)
    logEvents(`${err.no}: ${err.code}\t${err.syscall}\t${err.hostname}`, 'mongoErrLog.log')
})
```

**noteRoutes.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const notesController = require('../controllers/notesController')

router.route('/')
    .get(notesController.getAllNotes)
    .post(notesController.createNewNote)
    .patch(notesController.updateNote)
    .delete(notesController.deleteNote)

    module.exports = router
```

And finally **notesController.js**

```
const User = require('../models/User')
const Note = require('../models/Note')
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')

// @desc Get all notes 
// @route GET /notes
// @access Private
const getAllNotes = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    // Get all notes from MongoDB
    const notes = await Note.find().lean()

    // If no notes 
    if (!notes?.length) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No notes found' })
    }

    // Add username to each note before sending the response 
    // See Promise.all with map() here: https://youtu.be/4lqJBBEpjRE 
    // You could also do this with a for...of loop
    const notesWithUser = await Promise.all(notes.map(async (note) => {
        const user = await User.findById(note.user).lean().exec()
        return { ...note, username: user.username }
    }))

    res.json(notesWithUser)
})

// @desc Create new note
// @route POST /notes
// @access Private
const createNewNote = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { user, title, text } = req.body

    // Confirm data
    if (!user || !title || !text) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'All fields are required' })
    }

    // Check for duplicate title
    const duplicate = await Note.findOne({ title }).lean().exec()

    if (duplicate) {
        return res.status(409).json({ message: 'Duplicate note title' })
    }

    // Create and store the new user 
    const noteObject = { user, title, text}
    const note = await Note.create(noteObject)

    if (note) { // Created 
        return res.status(201).json({ message: 'New note created' })
    } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid note data received' })
    }

})

// @desc Update a note
// @route PATCH /notes
// @access Private
const updateNote = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { id, user, title, text, completed } = req.body

    // Confirm data
    if (!id || !user || !title || !text || typeof completed !== 'boolean') {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'All fields are required' })
    }

    // Confirm note exists to update
    const note = await Note.findById(id).exec()

    if (!note) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Note not found' })
    }

    // Check for duplicate title
    const duplicate = await Note.findOne({ title }).lean().exec()

    // Allow renaming of the original note 
    if (duplicate && duplicate?._id.toString() !== id) {
        return res.status(409).json({ message: 'Duplicate note title' })
    }

    note.user = user
    note.title = title
    note.text = text
    note.completed = completed

    const updatedNote = await note.save()

    res.json(`'${updatedNote.title}' updated`)
})

// @desc Delete a note
// @route DELETE /notes
// @access Private
const deleteNote = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.body

    // Confirm data
    if (!id) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Note ID required' })
    }

    // Confirm note exists to delete 
    const note = await Note.findById(id).exec()

    if (!note) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Note not found' })
    }

    const result = await note.deleteOne()

    const reply = `Note '${result.title}' with ID ${result._id} deleted`

    res.json(reply)
})

module.exports = {
    getAllNotes,
    createNewNote,
    updateNote,
    deleteNote
}
```

The GET request for notes works just fine, and the POST requests also return status code 400 when given invalid/incomplete data. They just don't work when I enter the user ID, the title, and the text - in that it never finishes execution.[Here is the JSON text I entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHmlJ.png)

Comment: What's the health/status of the database cluster? Is there a PRIMARY?

Comment: There is a Primary and two secondaries, if I am understanding this right.

Comment: UPDATE: I manually created a note instance on MongoDB and the PATCH, GET, and DELETE operations work just fine via Postman. It is only POST that takes too long.